Why did a T get added to the word "them"?
If you look back to middle English, you find the word 'them' was usually spelled 'hem'. For instance the Form of curry:

Take Pigges yskaldid and quarter hem and seeþ hem in water and salt,
take hem and lat hem kele. take persel sawge. and grynde it with brede
and zolkes of ayrenn harde ysode. temper it up with vyneger sum what
thyk. and, lay the Pygges in a vessell. and the sewe onoward and serue
it forth.

This makes sense really. The way the word is said, that whole 'thorn' th.... It doesn't really involve the letter T in its normal form.
If you look at English's second closest relative, Dutch, there 'hen' is the word for them. In Danish, which has heavy historic linkes with English, its 'dem'.   In more distant German its  ihnen , which certainly sounds closer to hem than them.
"'em' is certainly how the word is most commonly said across much of Britain.
So. Can anyone shed light on the development here? How did we come to end up adding a t onto the word?

Looking up them etymology led me to https://www.etymonline.com/word/they, which explains it pretty well.

Much of English comes from Old Norse, more than one might think at first.  Having learned a bit of /French, German, and Dutch, I subsequently went to Norway and started seeing cognates of a large number of English words that I hadn't even realized didn't have cognates in the first three languages.

There's a "t" because it's pronounced /ð/! But I assume you're not asking why that sound is spelt "th". The OED gives a load of cognates for they: Old Icelandic þeir, Old Norwegian þeir, þæir, Old Swedish þēr, Old Danish the, thæ. And a bit more of a detailed story, but the essentials are the same as on etymonline.com.
